# How to build a function for uasort to place children under parents

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that stores id > parent

What I want to do is sort this array using the uasort function in PHP to place all childern under their parents

so if I have

```
ID>>PARENT
1 >> 0
2 >> 0
3 >> 1
4 >> 1
5 >> 0
6 >> 2
7 >> 6
8 >> 6
9 >> 2
```

THEN I need to return the results like this

```
ID
1
3
4
2
6
7
8
9
```

My array is like this

```
Array (
     [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [PARENT] => 0
        ) 

     [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [PARENT] => 0
        ) 

     [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [PARENT] => 1
        ) 

     [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [PARENT] => 1
        ) 

     [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [PARENT] => 0
        ) 
     [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6
            [PARENT] => 2
        ) 

     [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] =>7
            [PARENT] => 6
        ) 

     [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] =>8
            [PARENT] => 6
        ) 

     [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] =>9
            [PARENT] => 9
        ) 
)
```

This is what I have done

```
uasort($survey, 'cmp');

print_r($survey);


function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['parent_id'] == $b['parent_id']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['parent_id'] < $b['parent_id']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

this code sort all the parent first and then the children after the parents and not underneath them.

Can some one help me with this issue please?

Comment: If you continue to duplicate your posts, you will soon find yourself unable to make any more posts... if you are not already there.

Answer (score 3):

`uasort()` and friends are not quite fit for purpouse here: Assume you want to compare the last child of parent N with the next parent N+1 - the child should compare as smaller. If the same child had parent N+1, it would need to compare bigger. This is doable, as long as you have only one level, but it gets qugly, if you have more.

I recommend you use another approach:

- Step 1: Group entries into an array of arrays by parent
- Step 2: Sort the sub-arrays individually
- Step 3: Flatten the structure by recursion:
- - start with current parent id 0 and an empty final
- - repeat
- - - move the first row of the array with the current parent id to the end of the final array
- - - if none available, return
- - - recurse with the id of this row as the current parent id

**Edit**

Some code, as requested: This works for me with your example.

Please be aware, that your example seems a bit stretchy: You desired output lacks the ID 5, and while most root nodes use 0 as a parent, ID 9 uses ID==PARENT.

```
<?php
function flatten($parentid, &$parents, &$final) {
  if (!isset($parents[$parentid])) return;
  $children=$parents[$parentid];
  unset($parents[$parentid]);

  //repeat
  while (true) {
    //move the first row of the array with the current parent id to the end of the final array
    $child=array_shift($children);

    //if none available, return
    if (!$child) break;
    $final[]=$child;

    //recurse with the id of this row as the current parent id
    flatten($child['ID'],$parents,$final);
  }
}

//Step 1: Group entries into an array of arrays by parent
//In your input, both PARENT==ID and PARENT==0 are used for root nodes
$parents=array();
foreach ($input as $item) {
  $parent=$item['PARENT'];
  if ($parent==$item['ID']) $parent=0;
  if (isset($parents[$parent])) $parents[$parent][$item['ID']]=$item;
  else $parents[$parent]=array($item['ID']=>$item);
}

//Step 2: Sort the sub-arrays individually
foreach ($parents as $item) ksort($item);

//Step 3: Flatten the structure by recursion:
//start with current parent id 0 and an empty final
$final=array();
flatten(0, $parents, $final);

//Done
print_r($final);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with some code here? I am trying to write this code but I am not coming up with the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and build a sorted version.

```
$arr2 = array();
    foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
        if ( $v['PARENT'] > 0 ) {
            $arr2[$v['PARENT']][$k] = $v;   
        }
    }
ksort($arr2);
```

Using your example (and correcting the mismatch in your info), I get the following.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 3
                    [PARENT] => 1
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 4
                    [PARENT] => 1
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 6
                    [PARENT] => 2
                )
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9
                    [PARENT] => 2
                )
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7
                    [PARENT] => 6
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 8
                    [PARENT] => 6
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This is not working. Do you have to include the ID somehow in the solution?